# Bayesian Rolling Poisson Regression in Jags (via R2jags)

Tags: r, bayesian, r2jags

**The Problem**

I have a small dataset (N=100). I need to run a Poisson regression, but excluding one observation at a time (hence, a *Rolling* Poisson Regression).

There are several predictors in the equation, but I care about one (call it **b.x**). My idea is to see how much b.x varies across the 100 models. Then, I'd like to plot these 100 point estimates with the effect sizes on the Y-axis, and the model number in the X-axis.

In summary, I need the following:

1. Run a Rolling Poisson Regression in JAGS (via R2jags).
2. After getting the estimates, plot them.

**Please note that my Poisson model in JAGS is running fine** (below is a sample toy of my model/data). However, **I haven't been able to implement the "Rolling" version**.

**The Self-Contained Example**

```
# clear R
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")

# load libraries
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman) 
p_load(R2jags)


# Toy Data
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(n=N)  # standard Normal predictor
y <- rpois(n=N, lambda = 1)  # Poisson DV


# model
model <- function() {
    ## Likelihood
    for(i in 1:N){
            y[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
            log(lambda[i]) <- 
                    mu + # intercept
                    b.x*x[i]
            }
    ## Priors 
    mu ~  dnorm(0, 0.01) ## intercept
    b.x ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    }

# list elements
data.list <- list(N = N, y = y, x = x)

# run model
model.fit <- jags(
    data=data.list,
    inits=NULL,
    parameters.to.save = c("b.x"),
    n.chains = 1,
    n.iter = 20,
    n.burnin = 2, 
    model.file=model,
    progress.bar = "none")
```

Ok. That's the model. In `model.fit` there is **b.x**, the coefficient I have to get 100 times. With my current code, I am able to obtain it just once, with the full dataset. However, I need to obtain it a second time with the first row of the df excluded, and then a third time but with the second row of the df excluded, and so on and so forth. And then, plot all these **b.x**'s.

---

Now, just for the sake of the example, I will create a simple table, just to signal that I need the first element (the coefficient of of **b.x**).

```
## I sourced this function below from    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkarreth/JKmisc/master/mcmctab.R

# Function to Create Table
mcmctab <- function(sims, ci = .8, digits = 2){

    require(coda) 

    if(class(sims) == "jags" | class(sims) == "rjags"){
            sims <- as.matrix(as.mcmc(sims))
    }
    if(class(sims) == "bugs"){
            sims <- sims$sims.matrix
    }  
    if(class(sims) == "mcmc"){
            sims <- as.matrix(sims)
    }    
    if(class(sims) == "mcmc.list"){
            sims <- as.matrix(sims)
    }      
    if(class(sims) == "stanfit"){
            stan_sims <- rstan::As.mcmc.list(sims)
            sims <- as.matrix(stan_sims)
    }      


    dat <- t(sims)

    mcmctab <- apply(dat, 1,
                     function(x) c(Mean = round(mean(x), digits = digits), # Posterior mean
                                   SD = round(sd(x), digits = 3), # Posterior SD
                                   Lower = as.numeric(
                                           round(quantile(x, probs = c((1 - ci) / 2)), 
                                                 digits = digits)), # Lower CI of posterior
                                   Upper = as.numeric(
                                           round(quantile(x, probs = c((1 + ci) / 2)), 
                                                 digits = digits)), # Upper CI of posterior
                                   Pr. = round(
                                           ifelse(mean(x) > 0, length(x[x > 0]) / length(x),
                                                  length(x[x < 0]) / length(x)), 
                                           digits = digits) # Probability of posterior >/< 0
                     ))
    return(t(mcmctab))
}


# this is the coefficient I need, but with different data frames.
mcmctab(model.fit)[1,1]
```

Sorry I can't even provide an attempted solution here. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# clear R
rm(list=ls())

# load libraries
library(R2jags)

# Toy Data
set.seed(123) # set RNG seed for reproducibility
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(n=N)  # standard Normal predictor
y <- rpois(n=N, lambda = 1)  # Poisson DV

# model
model <- function() {
  ## Likelihood
  for(i in 1:N){
    y[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    log(lambda[i]) <- 
      mu + # intercept
      b.x*x[i]
  }
  ## Priors 
  mu ~  dnorm(0, 0.01) ## intercept
  b.x ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
}

# list elements
data.list <- list() # create empty list to fill in next line

# fill list with one data set for each step, with one row excluded per step
for(i in 1:100){
  data.list[[i]] <- list(N = 99, y = y[-i], x = x[-i])
}

# Starting value for reproducibility
model.inits <- function(){
  list("b.x" = 0)
}

# run model
model.fit <- list() # again, create empty list first

for(i in 1:100){  # use loop here to fit one model per data set
model.fit[[i]] <- jags(
  data=data.list[[i]],
  inits=NULL,
  parameters.to.save = c("b.x"),
  n.chains = 1,
  n.iter = 20,
  n.burnin = 2, 
  model.file=model,
  progress.bar = "none")
}


# helper function for output
devtools::source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkarreth/JKmisc/master/mcmctab.R")

# create empty data frame to be filled with estimation results per data set
tab <- data.frame(index = c(1:100), b = rep(NA, 100), lower = rep(NA, 100), upper = rep(NA, 100))

# fill with estimates, using mcmctab to extract mean & lower & upper CIs
for(i in 1:100){
  tab[i, 2] <- mcmctab(model.fit[[i]])[1, 1]
  tab[i, 3] <- mcmctab(model.fit[[i]])[1, 3]
  tab[i, 4] <- mcmctab(model.fit[[i]])[1, 4]
}

# plot results
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = tab, aes(x = b, y = index)) + geom_point() + geom_segment(aes(x = lower, xend = upper, yend = index))
p
```

[image: output]

I thank [Johannes Karreth](http://www.jkarreth.net) for kindly providing this great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop or one of the `apply` family members to exclude one observation at a time:

```
sims <- lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  data.list <- list(N = N - 1, y = y[-i], x = x[-i])
  # run model
  model.fit <- jags(
      data=data.list,
      inits=NULL,
      parameters.to.save = c("b.x"),
      n.chains = 1,
      n.iter = 20,
      n.burnin = 2, 
      model.file=model,
      progress.bar = "none")
  return(model.fit)
})
```

You can then extract your quantity of interest by looping through the output:

```
sapply(sims, function(x) x$BUGSoutput$mean$b.x)
#  [1] -0.018966261 -0.053383364 -0.030193649 -0.097046841 -0.026258934
#  [6] -0.005486296  0.084811315 -0.047736880  0.142379194 -0.026583145
# <snip>
```